# Join by attribute KeyError

Tags: attribute-joins, error, qgis-2.18

I'm trying to join a shp and a CSV, by joinbyattibutes, by the Column "KOMNAVN" 
in QGIS 2.18.

[image]

[image]

However, I get this log message error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search for the tool `Convert Geometry Type` and convert your layer to the type that should be.

I faced this problem, it was a problem of a strange geometry type that was not supported.